# Looking for ASP.NET MVC Style templates

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am looking for pre-defined style sheet which can be used to replace the out of box style sheet which comes with MVC templates. http://mvccontribgallery.codeplex.com/ looks the step in right direction but there are no downloads. Yes I can do this myself but there must be something someone has released out for the community.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I wish Microsoft paid a bit more attention to mvccontribgallery. C'mon guys/gals you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the HTML5 Boiler Plate.

https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/style.css

You might want to take a look at http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ as well.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/), [Blueprint CSS](http://blueprintcss.org/), [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) (specifically `.ui-helper-reset`), just to name a few...

Answer (score 1):

Not EXACTLY what you're looking for, but I suggest the [Twitter Bootstrap toolkit](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap)